# Sequence of empirical means converges to the empirical mean of the limits?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, strong-convergence

Let $S_n=1/n\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,n}$ , where $X_{i,n}$ are random variables such that for all $i=1,\cdots \infty$ we have
$X_{i,n}\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ almost surely.
Doest $S_n \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ almost surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true even for constant r.v.'s Take $X_{i,n}=\frac  i n$, for example. $ S_n \to \frac 1  2$ in this case.

Comment: Is there some additional conditional that will make this true? Something on the rate of convergence maybe?